# Горизонтальная прокрутка внутри flexbox с максимальной шириной

Tags: css, layout, jade, stylus, flexbox

Есть пример:
http://codepen.io/LestaD/pen/ZOpBzM?editors=1100

```
main
  aside
  content
    section Hello
    footer
      .panel
        .avatar
        .text
          div Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at
        .actions
          .act
          .act
          .act
```

В котором необходимо,чтобы:

- `footer` занимал максимальную доступную ширину (ширина экрана - ширина `section`)
- `.avatar` и `.actions` имели фиксированную ширину
- `.text` занимал всю свободную оставшуюся ширину в `footer`
- текст внутри `.text` скрывался (`overflow: hidden`)
- текст может быть как очень длинным так и очень коротким, `.text` должен быть максимальной ширины, но не должен менять ширину `footer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akwbvR, добавил только обводки т.к. Ваш код удовлетворяет условиям.

1. Тег `content` не стоит использовать, поэтому он был заменен на `article`.

   > This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time.
   >   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/content
2. `footer` занимает всю доступную ширину, обведен красным.
3. Если Вы в codepen нажмете Change View и в Editor Layout выберете левый или правый вид, то сможете изменять ширину окна просмотра результата. Изменяя ширину, Вы увидете, что `.avatar` и `.actions` имеют фиксированную ширину (`.actions` обведен черным), текст внутри `.text` скрывается и не изменяет ширину `footer`.

Советую почитать статью http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/, чтобы лучше разобраться с flexbox.

Я бы вот так сверстал http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akwbdQ